# Exponent problem: if $m^n=n^{m^{n/m}}$ and $m,n>1$, prove that $m=n$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $m^n=n^{m^{n/m}}$ and $m$ and $n$ are real numbers such that $m,n>1$, prove that $m=n$.

---

I was playing around with exponents when I found this hypothesis. It appears to be true by plugging it into Desmos, but personally I can't find a mathematically rigorous proof for it. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you require $m, n$ to be integers?

Comment: Nope, they are just real numbers greater than 1. I'll edit my post to make that more clear.

Comment: Use the following idea. $\frac{lnx}{x}$ is decreasing function whenever $x>e$, so if you can somehow compare $n^{m^{n/m}}$ with $n^{m}$ supposing at the same time that both of them are $>e$ , you will have the answer. To do so, take 2  cases $n>m>e$ and $e<n<m$. For both cases you'll have the answer. So whenever $n>e$ and $m>e$ you'll have $n=m$. For the cases $n>e>m$ and $m>e>n$ you can take log, and see that signs differ. However for the reaming case you should have in mind that log is increasing and the same comparison wouldn't do. So here should the role of $n/m$ term come into light.

Comment: Also @WhatsUp if you are interested

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I actually believed that this was correct, and I had a very badly written "proof" on my scrap paper. The idea is similar to yours, taking logarithms, derivatives, etc. and it's chaotic and ugly and boring, and I don't know whether there's an error. Thus at some point I lost interest in this problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Case, $1< n<m$.** Let $n>1$ be fixed and define $$f(m):=m^n-n^{m^{\frac nm}}.$$

Then, by some straight-forward but long calculations (this time verified with [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdm+n%5Em%5E%28n%2Fm%29) ), we get $$f'(m)=nm^{n-1}+m^{\frac{n}{m}-2}\cdot n^{m^{\frac{n}{m}}+1}\cdot(\ln{m}-1)\cdot\ln(n).$$

**Lemma.** For $1\le n<m$, $f'(m)>0$.

*Proof.* If $m\geq e$, then the first summand is strictly positive and the second one is non-negative so we are done. Suppose thus that $n<m<e$. Then we note using $-1<\ln m - 1<0$ and $0\le\ln n<1$ that
$$f'(m)>nm^{n-1}-m^{\frac{n}{m}-2}\cdot n^{m^{\frac nm}+1}.$$

So $f'(m)>0$ is proven by:
\begin{align}
&\underbrace{m^{\frac nm-2} \cdot n^{m^{\frac nm}+1}}_{\le m^{-1}\cdot n^{m+1}}\le nm^{n-1} \\
\impliedby &n^{m+1} \le n\cdot m^n \\
\iff &n^m \le m^n \\
\iff &\frac{\ln(n)}n \le \frac{\ln(m)}m \\
\impliedby &n<m<e.\square
\end{align}
Since $f(n)=0$ and $f'(m)>0$ for all $n<m$, we conclude that $f(n)<0$ whenever $n<m$ so that there are no solutions to your equation for $n<m$.

**2. Case, $1<m<n$.** Now, let $m>1$ be fixed.
By taking $\log_m$ on both sides we see that your equation is equivalent to
\begin{equation}\tag 1\label 1 n=m^\frac{n}{m}\cdot\log_m(n).\end{equation}

*Redefine* $f(n):=m^\frac{n}{m}\cdot\log_m(n)-n$.

We have $f(1)=-1$ and $f(m)=0$.

Note that \begin{equation}\tag 2\label 2 f'(n)=\frac{\partial}{\partial n} \left(m^\frac{n}{m}\cdot\log_m(n)-n\right)=m^{\frac nm}\cdot\left(\frac{\ln(n)}{m}+\frac{1}{n\ln(m)}\right)-1.\end{equation}

If we can prove that the expression in \eqref{2} is $>0$ for all $n>m,\infty$, we have proven that $f(n)>0$ for all $n>m$ so that there are no solutions when $n>m$.

For all $n>m$, we have \begin{equation}\tag 3\label 3m^{\frac nm}\cdot\left(\frac{\ln(n)}{m}+\frac{1}{n\ln(m)}\right)> \ln(n)+\frac 1n\frac{m}{\ln(m)}.\end{equation} We need to prove that the RHS of \eqref{3} is $>1$:

Both terms on the RHS of \eqref{3} are positive. If $n\geq e$ then we are done since $\ln(n)\geq 1$.

Otherwise, note that $e>n>m$ so that $\frac{m}{\ln(m)}>e$ (the last function is decreasing and attains the value $e$ at $m=e$). It follows that $\frac1n\frac{m}{\ln(m)}>\frac1e\cdot e=1$ so we are done aswell.

**It follows that the only solution is $n=m$.**

Comment: Your calculation of $f'(m)$ in the first case doesn't look correct to me. Mind writing down the details?

Comment: @WhatsUp Indeed there was an error in my calculations; I will update my answer shortly. Thanks for telling me!

Comment: @WhatsUp It is now fixed... Note that the $n$ from the derivative of the polynomial now comes in really handy